# How to save newsletter subscription status?

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I use this code to set the subscription status:

```
const STATUS_SUBSCRIBED     = 1;
const STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE     = 2;
const STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED   = 3;
const STATUS_UNCONFIRMED    = 4;

...

$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customerID = $customer->getId();

$customerModel = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
        ->load($customerID);

Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')
        ->setCustomerId($customerModel->getId())
        ->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
        ->setEmail("myemail@foo.com")
        ->save();
```

But the state is not saved and the checkbox* is not getting set in the backend. What am I doing wrong?

*the checkbox I talk about is at: *Customers -> manage customers -> 'enter a customer account' -> Newsletter*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me --

**in Guest case--**

```
$email = "test@gmail.com";

$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
$subscriber->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$subscriber->setSubscriberStatus(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
$subscriber->setEmail($email);
$subscriber->setCustomerId(0);
$subscriber->save();
```

**in case of customer email -**

```
$email = "test@gmail.com";
$customerID = 1;

$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
$subscriber->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$subscriber->setSubscriberStatus(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
$subscriber->setEmail($email);
$subscriber->setCustomerId($customerID);
$subscriber->save();
```

Comment: Thanks so far, we are almost there!! It does work if I use STATUS_SUBSCRIBED, but not if I use STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED ._. how can I unsubscribe a user?

Comment: it works well for unsubscribed case with Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED

Comment: Nope, I tried it. Won't work. The checkbox is still set.

Comment: can you paste your code for unsubscribed ?

Comment: It seems like I strictly have to write `$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);` like you did, then it works! If I put `loadByEmail($email)` in a separate line e.g. `$subscriber->loadByEmail($email);`  then it does not work.
That was my culprit. But it does not work if I use another email adress then the one used to register the account.

Comment: in case of "another email adress then the one used to register the account", code under  "in Guest case" (in my above answer) should work.